# Uploading Image to the server asynchronously (iphone)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I Upload an Image Asynchronously to the server in iphone...please help me in this regard....?

Comment: What kind of server? Upload via what? HTTP POST?

Comment: It's a web server...and I want to upload via HTTP POST